# Buggy UI with Chrome and Sitecore 9.0u1

Tags: content-editor, sheer-ui

I just installed Sitecore 9 Update 1 and I'm going through trying to set up some security rights. In Chrome 64 (latest version), I keep seeing little flashes as modals open, but when I click the Add button for Assign Security Rights, I'll either get just a gray screen with no Add an Account window, or if I tab off and back I get the window, but it's useless...if I mouse over anything, the UI starts to vanish.

This works fine in IE 11 and Firefox 58. All instances are on a Windows Server 2016 VM acting as a dev environment. Has anyone else seen this behavior with Chrome 64 and Sitecore 9 Update 1?

UPDATE: This isn't happening in every case of using security assignment, but even in Chrome incognito mode I can make it repeat. This is a freshly-installed VM, so no extensions were added to Chrome that didn't ship with it.

1. Go to the Desktop and switch to the Core database.
2. Open the Content Editor.
3. Search for "publish" and click on "Publish Site".
4. On the Security tab, click the Assign button.
5. You can see bits of the next UI but it's unusable.

This appears to be happening for any item in the Core database that already has security assigned to it. I assigned some security to the Home item in the Master database, and the behavior is what you'd expect. But any item in Core in that same folder as "Publish Site" (/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Left/) is giving me the same experience if it has security already.

Comment: Is same behavior in incognito mode with disabled extensions? (I guess that some extension can cause it)

Comment: Added more info, this appears to be a more specific case, but is replicable in incognito mode.

Comment: Ken, When it is occurring, does resizing the window make it look better?  I've been having similar issues with some of the modals in Sitecore, specifically in Chrome.  I figured my laptop just sucked.

Comment: I haven't tried resizing, and I actually just blew my VM away to do some reset on the basics. But I did open a new tab and flipped between them...when I flipped back, the UI looked better, but then when I moused over it the contents would start vanishing.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that for using sitecore cms, IE or firefox is preferable as they are more stable with sitecore than chrome. If i am not mistaken, it should be in the Sitecore Professional Development book. Will post the link if I find it

Comment: Thanks Hishaam...that's very interesting actually. When I've been working with Sitecore 8.x I haven't had these issues, but if I recall right, didn't the underlying UI model switch to Angular in Sitecore 9? I'm not sure of all of the details, so I don't know if there's some oddball effect going on, or if I just didn't see this in the 8.x sites because I hadn't been to those branches.

Comment: I've put in a support ticket for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible the latest minor Google update around Valentine's Day fixed things...I just heard back from Sitecore support who sent me a Screencast, and it wasn't reproducing the issue I found (I think they found another though). When I went into my local environment, I couldn't reproduce it either. Curious how others are doing, but I'm marking this done.